# C# ASP.NET Code doesn't insert data into my database, but doesn't throw any errors either

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project for a class. One of the requirements is that my program pulls information from a few textboxes on a web form and stores the values into a database. I have pulled information out of a database and figured putting stuff into one would be roughly the same process. When I tried however I get no errors, but when I open the database up there is nothing there either.

Code:

```
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbCommand com;

con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\D40010490\Desktop\GMDatabase.accdb");
com = con.CreateCommand();
try
{
    con.Open();
    lblError.Text = "Successfully Connected to Database";

    String firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    String lastName = txtLastName.Text;
    String email = txtEmail.Text;
    String password = txtPassword.Text;
    String cpassword = txtCPassword.Text;
    String Description = txtDesc.Text;
    com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users "
           + "(lastname, firstname, email, password) "
           + "VALUES (" + "'" +lastName+"'"
           + "'" + firstName +"'"+ "'"+email+"'"+ "'"+password+"');";

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

please advise.

Comment: FYI, the way you are building your `CommandText` property's value contains a whole host of SQL Injection vulnerabilities. I suggest you look into using a parameterized query.

Answer (score 7):

You never actually *execute* the command:

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users "...

com.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

You should also get in the habit of using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of concatenating SQL (*especially* when dealing with users and passwords).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` in order to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Cidade have reason , always you want insert in database you should execute the retrieve, check very good your code and bug if is necesary for resolve...